VBA Incorrect Date Format
I have a set of macros that automate a booking system.
There are 3 users of the system.
the macros work fine for 2 of the users but the third has a very annoying issue.
When writing the date of the visit to an excel workbook it is written in mm/dd/yyyy format.
The macro itself has it in dd/mm/yyyy format.
Any ideas as to how this happens?
I have tried looking at system settings on the users laptop with no luck.

Please post the code which is writing this date to the workbook. The issue is likely related to cell formatting rather than the value written to the cell. It's also worth checking how each user is opening the file: a lot of Microsoft 365 tenants default to MM/DD/YYYY for the web app.

When writing the date of the visit to an excel workbook it is written in mm/dd/yyyy format Tell them to write the values as you need. Probably they are forcing the dates as text because they don't know.
